# How to get DistributionChart to show normalised densities?

Tags: plotting, distributions, charts

I am having some issue getting `DistributionChart` to show bin widths as expected, or perhaps it is in my interpretation of the plots.

I have four data sets, all of the same length, and plot them in the same graph:

```
DistributionChart[{
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000}],     
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000}], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], {1000}], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000}]}, 
Method -> {"BoxWidth" -> "Scaled"}]
```

This results in a plot of the same type as below:

[image]

Since all the data sets are the same size - 1000 elements - I would expect that the area of each plot should be the same. However, the third plot is much too small for that to be the case.

Does anyone know how I can get them to be comparable? In that the area would be the same across all four.

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 4):

```
{d1, d2, d3, d4} = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution @@ #, {1000}] & /@ 
  {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, .2}, {0, 1}};
```

**Using `PairedSmoothHistogram` and `Show` in combination with `Translate`:**

```
histograms = Quiet @ PairedSmoothHistogram[#, #, PlotStyle -> #2, 
     FillingStyle -> Lighter[#2], Filling -> Axis, Axes -> False, 
     Frame -> False, Spacings -> 0] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{{d1, d2, d3, d4}, ColorData[97]/@Range[4]}];

Show[Graphics@ MapIndexed[Translate[#[[1]], {3 #2[[1]], 0}] &, histograms], 
 Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {{2, 2}, {1, 1}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
  {Thread[{Range[3, 12, 3], CharacterRange["A", "D"]}],  Automatic}}]
```

[image]

**Using `DistributionChart` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:**

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF = Module[{col = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}, 
    Translate[Quiet @ PairedSmoothHistogram[#2, #2, PlotStyle -> col, 
       FillingStyle -> Lighter[col], Filling -> Axis, Axes -> False, 
       Frame -> False, Spacings -> 0][[1]], {#3[[1]] (Mean@#[[1]]), 0}]] &;

ll = 4; δ = 4;
Show[DistributionChart[Thread[{d1, d2, d3, d4} -> δ], 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF, ChartStyle -> 1], 
 Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, δ - 1}, {1, 1}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
  {Thread[{Range[δ, δ  ll, δ], CharacterRange["A", "D"]}], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The vertical height is determined by the range of the data. The method you chose sets the maximum width to be proportional to the square root of the data sizes. Since the data sizes are identical, the maximum widths are identical. The shape shows how the data is distributed across the range of the data. Compare your results with different size data sets

```
DistributionChart[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {10000}], 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000}], 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], {400}], 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]}, 
 Method -> {"BoxWidth" -> "Scaled"}]
```

[image]

```
DistributionChart[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {10000}], 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000}], 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], {400}], 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]}, 
 Method -> {"BoxWidth" -> "Fixed"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to achieve a normalised density though? By this I mean that all data sets would be the same area. Best, Ben